# clicking slippery "ElementNotVisibleException" button selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

https://gist.github.com/codyc4321/724f05aca8f6775e2fc1

Hi, bitbucket changed their login page, and is giving me a hassle. Based on the following gist, using `driver.click_button` causes:

```
ElementNotVisibleException at /bitbucket/create-repo
Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmpSNzLIl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9981)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpSNzLIl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12517)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpSNzLIl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpSNzLIl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpSNzLIl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

using `driver.submit_form` causes error in the browser itself:

[image]

using `driver.activate_hidden_element` causes:

```
ElementNotVisibleException at /bitbucket/create-repo
Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

`activate_hidden_element` failing really took the wind outta my sails for the last 5 minutes. How can I click this stonewalling button? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem is actually in your `locate_element` method.

When you check for the xpath: `"//button[normalize-space(text())='{text}']"` it finds a button successfully but it is *not* the login button you are looking for. If you switch that with the `input` xpath: `"//input[@value='{text}']"` it finds the right `input` and successfully logs you in.

You should also remove the last two lines in the `BitbucketDriver.login()` method because the line `self.click_button(search_text="Log in")` throws an `AttributeError`.

Your `locate_element` method should look like this:

```
def locate_element(self, search_text, xpaths=None):
    if not xpaths:
        xpaths = [ "//input[@value='{text}']", "//button[normalize-space(text())='{text}']",
                  "//a[child::span[normalize-space(text())='{text}']]", "//a[normalize-space(text())='{text}']"]
    try:
        return self.driver.find_element_by_id(search_text)
    except:
        try:
            return self.driver.find_element_by_name(search_text)
        except:
            try:
                return self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(search_text)
            except:
                for path in xpaths:
                    try:
                        return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(path.format(text=search_text))
                    except:
                        pass
    return None
```

Comment: @codyc4321 glad I could help!